# DEFINE() macro usage in expressinions

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

So I defined..

```
#define RADIAN(x) x*3.14159265f/180.0f
```

and then used it like this:

```
RADIAN(theta-90)
```

My program constantly gave me incorrect results, it took me a couple hours to realize that there was a huge difference between the above statement and the statement below.

```
RADIAN((theta-90))
```

Now my program is running perfectly fine. Why is the first statement incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#define` makes just text substitution, so `RADIAN(theta-90)` was really `theta-90*3.14159265f/180.0f`, what obviously wasn't what you meant. Try

```
#define RADIAN(x) ((x)*3.14159265f/180.0f)
```

instead.

Comment: Or better still, `inline float RADIAN(float x) {return x*3.14159265f/180.0f;}` to avoid all the pitfalls of macros.

Comment: +1 If you really want to use macros, always add parenthesis around the arguments, as @x13n did, and beware of other pitfalls, including that because it is *text* substitution, the expression might be evalueated more than once: `#define MAX( x, y ) ( (x)<(y) ? (y) : (x) )` will evaluate one of `x` or `y` twice, so `MAX( sqrt(100), sqrt(4) );` will call `sqrt(100)` twice and `sqrt(4)` once... Things are much simpler with inlined functions :)

Answer (score 4):

Macro's largley do text based replacement so

```
RADIAN(theta-90)
```

expands to:

```
theta - 90* 3.14159265f/180.0f
```

which because of operator precedence, evaluates as:

```
theta - (90* 3.14159265f/180.0f)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are all correct. However, one point has not yet been made...

This is C++, not C. Stop using preprocessor macros.

Comment: In this particular case, I don't think there is any difference between C and C++, the macro should be substituted by an inlined function: `inline float radian( float x )`, the same way in C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, in the first case **X** will be replaced by (theta-90) so your function would evaluate to:

```
theta - 90* 3.14159265f/180.0f
```